# in which scope should i call stopSelf()?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, ondestroy

I've seen many question about the subject, but still im having problems using stopSelf() as the service doesnt call onDestroy() after calling stopSelf, yet is not appearing on the running apps tab on settings

I use the service a bit differently...

My service binds to a runnable task, and each time the task is finished, it calls a method on the service which checks if there are more tasks to be done, and if not it calls the stopSelf().

By my logic since I'm inside the service class, this.stopSelf() should refer to the current instance of the service (I got only this service running, and it binds up to 3 tasks each time).

I also know that the system will call onDestroy "on her terms" and not immediately. still I've been waiting for more than 10-20 minutes and no onDestroy is called

Some code for better understanding:

The Service:

```
public class MediaDownloadService extends Service {

private DBHelper helper;
private ExecutorService executor;
private static final String TAG = "com.sharongur,root.myapplication";
private final IBinder sharonsBinder = new MyLocalBinder();
File file;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return sharonsBinder;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    helper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
    executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2,3,3000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    Log.e("requestsExists", helper.requestsExists() + "");
   if(helper.requestsExists()){
        // map of the index of the request and the string of the absolute path of the request
        Map<Integer,String> requestMap = helper.getRequestsToExcute(3);
        Set<Integer> keySet = requestMap.keySet();
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = keySet.iterator();
        Log.e("MAP",requestMap.toString());
        //checks if the DB requests exists
        if(!requestMap.isEmpty()){
            //execute them and delete the DB entry
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                int iteratorNext = iterator.next();
                Log.e("ITREATOR", iteratorNext + "");
                file = new File(requestMap.get(iteratorNext));
                Log.e("file", file.toString());
                Log.e("thread Opened", "Thread"+iteratorNext);
                executor.submit(new MyTask(file, getApplicationContext(), iteratorNext), 1);
                helper.requestTaken(iteratorNext);
            }
        }
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void startNewTask(){
    Log.e("requestExists", helper.requestsExists()+"");
    if(helper.requestsExists()){
        Map<Integer,String> requestMap = helper.getRequestsToExcute(1);
        Set<Integer> keySet = requestMap.keySet();
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = keySet.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
                int iteratorNext = iterator.next();
                file = new File(requestMap.get(iteratorNext));
                Log.e("file", file.toString());
                Log.e("thread Opened", "Thread"+iteratorNext);
                executor.submit(new MyTask(file, getApplicationContext(), iteratorNext), 1);
                helper.requestTaken(iteratorNext);
            }
    }else{
        executor.shutdown();
        Log.e("stopself", "stop self after this");
        this.stopSelf();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.e("ONCREATE", "SERVICE CREATED");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e("ONDESTROY", "SERVICE DESTROYED");
    super.onDestroy();
}

public class MyLocalBinder extends Binder{
    MediaDownloadService getService(){
        return MediaDownloadService.this;
    }
}
```

The Task:

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable {

private File _file;
private Context context;
private DBHelper helper;
private int requestId;
private MediaDownloadService sharonsService;
boolean isBound = false;

public MyTask(File file, Context context, int requestId) {
    this._file = file;
    this.context = context;
    this.requestId = requestId;

}

@Override
public void run() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,MediaDownloadService.class);
    context.bindService(intent,sharonsConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        // some work
        sharonsService.startNewTask();
        helper.deleteRequest(requestId);
        context.unbindService(sharonsConnection);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Callable try", post.toString());

    }
}

private ServiceConnection sharonsConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
       MyLocalBinder binder = (MyLocalBinder) service;
        sharonsService = binder.getService();
        isBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        isBound = false;
    }
};
}
```

I suspect im using the method wrong somehow...
Maybe the this.stopSelf() refers to the instance that called the method? in the case its bind to the task and not the service

Comment: With regards to `onDestroy()`, if there is an outstanding binding to the service, I would not expect `stopSelf()` to cause the service to be destroyed, because the service is still in use.

Comment: @CommonsWare Well, I don't think I understand completely then.
Because I do unbind each task once its finished...
And in anycase, shouldn't I see the service running on the setting app->running? If you say he is still in use?
If there's a new thread that the service created, and the stopSelf is called, the service can die isn't it? the new thread will continue its work regardless of the service being up or not?

Comment: Is bindService opens a new service? If so I think that is my problem... MY tasks connect to the service on each task, in that case I create A LOT of service instances... each task actually. I thought the bindService only bind to an existing service... Is this the Problem?

Comment: "And in anycase, shouldn't I see the service running on the setting app->running?" -- I have not run a lot of tests to see what triggers apps to show up in that list. "the new thread will continue its work regardless of the service being up or not?" -- threads that you fork are independent of services. Services are signal to the OS that your process is doing work of value to the user, to try to keep your process around longer. We manage long-term background threads with services so that our process containing those threads is likely to live long enough for us to do our work.;

Comment: "Is bindService opens a new service?" -- no. Services are natural singletons. There will be zero or one running instance of your service at any point.

Comment: your Service overrides both `onStartCommand` and `onBind`, are you sure you want both **started** and **bound** Service? that is you call both `startService()` amd `bindService()` from your client?

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks a lot for the answers. Learning a lot from you
Regarding the original question, I ran a test with just one request to do, hence only one thread will be opened, so the only task that created calls the stopSelf(), In that case there's no way the service is still running after the stopSelf().

Anyway I thought when I return START_STICKY the service will run until I explicitly stop it, so how can it be that I called stopSelf() and it "ignores" me and skips onDestroy()? is anything else I can call? I cant use stopService cause its within the service itself.

Comment: @pskink I call startService() from the activity. then the onStartCommand initiate the Recursive Tasks job, the tasks then binds to the service. each task calls the next until the DB is empty.

I guess I don't fully understand the concept of binding, I did it so I can call the method startNewTask() in the service from the task itself

Comment: so i think that you dont need to call bindService

Comment: @pskink
Take a look:http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

"When the last client unbinds from the service, the system destroys the service (unless the service was also started by startService())."

So I guess thats not the problem :/

Comment: but it seems that your `unbindService` has no effect as your service is not yet bound (`bindService` is an async op)